# Android Animation Display prob

Tags: android

I wanna use an animation in my prog., but it is not seen on emulator. It opens MenuActivity class before animation resource.

Here is the code partition;

```
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
    ImageView girisLogo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.girisLogoImageView);
    anim.reset();
    girisLogo.clearAnimation();
    girisLogo.startAnimation(anim);

    anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(GirisActivity.this,MenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            GirisActivity.this.finish();
        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {}
    });
}
```

fade_in.xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="https://schemes.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <alpha
      android:fromAlpha = "0.0"
      android:toAlpha="1.0"
      android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
      android:duration="4000"
    />

</set>
```

I tried to use anim.serDuration(400); but result doesnt change.
Could you help me in this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Change *fade_in.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="4000" />
```

Also, if you want the new *Activity* to start when animation ends, place the code in `onAnimationEnd()`

Comment: Thanks for your help, anim is seen.